# C++ non platform-dependant sound

Tags: c++, audio, cross-platform

I need this: A c++ function that can output sounds onto a speaker, that is not platform dependant(like Beep()). I also need something that can output some real-time generated sounds, not a .wav file or so.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Use a cross platform toolkit that has audio support. Qt is one such toolkit. Although I have not used the audio so I can not comment on the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like: http://libsdl.org/index.php

It attempts to be a cross platform alternative to direct X.  The zlib license it uses is very permissive.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use, cross platform, free — choose 2 of that 3.

- Drop “cross platform” and use e.g. MIDI output for Windows.
- Drop “easy to use” and use [OpenAL](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html)
- Drop “free” and license [Miles Sound System](http://www.radgametools.com/miles.htm), I‘ve heard Win + MacOS + Linux license costs $5000 per product.